# Meta boxes only displayed when editing normal (default wp post_type) posts

Tags: php, custom-field, metabox

I've multiple meta boxes for my main/default post types.

I also have multiple post_types where this meta boxes make no sense.

Can you hint me on if/else function I would use on displaying meta boxes only on default post_type?

Comment: How did you add these meta boxes? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box Take a look at the 3rd argument

Comment: @janw I have working meta box system, just need to limit it.

Comment: Which one? There must be an option to set post type.

Comment: @SandroDzneladze I understand the question, but depending on the plugin/code the means to fix may be different.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `add_meta_box`, the 4th paramater should be what you're looking for.

```
add_meta_box( $id, $title, $callback, $post_type, $context, $priority, $callback_args );
```

Use http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box as a reference